# Does Blast have psychic abilities?

Tags: one-punch-man

In the Databook it is said Fubuki speculates with Blast having psychic abilities, and has the ability to command trillions of robots (with his psychic abilities presumably?).  And recently a video claims

> Blast read Tatsumaki's mind in the manga when he met her and rescued her, by putting his hand on her head.

I don't recall how was this shown in the webcomic but I believe the interaction was even shorter. Is this confirmed now?

Does Blast have psychic abilities?

Answer (score 1):

As of what I have witnessed so far I could say this about **Blast**:

> Blast teleports Saitama, Flashy Flash and Manako out of the underground

> Dimensional Travel: Blast possesses some sort of ability to generate portals which allow him to move through another dimension or transfer objects. When Blast generates a portal that resembles a black hole to teleport himself, Flashy Flash, Saitama, and Manako, he clasps his fists together and an infinity symbol appears across his fists

So, yes he has that power which can overthrow all of the S class Hero's [combined.](https://onepunchman.fandom.com/wiki/Blast#:%7E:text=In%20the%20databook%2C%20Fubuki%20speculates,S%2DClass%20all%20at%20once.)

Answer (score 0):

The mind-reading is implied, but not unequivocally asserted.  We see him see right through her feigned powerlessness, telling her with no uncertainty that he knows she had more than enough power to deal with the problem that was at hand, then approach Tatsumaki, place his hand on her head in a reassuring-a-child-by-patting-their-head manner, assure her she has something to use her powers for, then the next panel shows a picture of her sister (as a child), and he remarks that she has a lovely sister.  The sequence implies that Tatsumaki thinks of her sister when told she has something to fight for and protect other than herself, and Blast sees that mental image.  This is all significantly more detailed than what we've seen of the encounter in the webcomic.

However, the nature and origins of Blast's powers are poorly detailed and highly suspicious and vast.  He may have knowledge of Tatsumaki from other methods, from the mundane "dude did his research on the organization he was infiltrating/attacking" to the well-beyond-psychic.

> There are implications that there is a cosmic, even Lovecraftian, entity at the works.  This is implicitly the being connected to the cubes he is collecting, which we are told, by said entity, will grant any wish of power to anyone worthy.  It is very ambiguously suggested that Blast may have been the recipient of such a boon, and for all we know he now has cosmic power which grants him the ability to see underlying truths of reality in a way that goes beyond simple mind reading.  But then, perhaps he is not and his power has some other origin, but nevertheless may include or even go well beyond simple mind reading.